# IntelliJ Structural Search to find classes that implement A but not B

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

I'm trying to use IntelliJ 10.5's "structural search" feature to find classes that implement an interface, *A* but do not implement another interface, *B*.

By searching first for classes that implement *A*, and then limiting the search scope to 'previous search results,' it's easy to reduce this to just searching for classes that do not implement *B*, which is conceptually pretty simple. Unfortunately, I haven't yet managed to pull it off.

If I search for

```
class $clazz$ implements $B$ {}
```

and then tick 'invert condition' in the text constraints for variable B, it seems to find 'all classes that implement something other than *B*' even if they also implement *B*. I've also tried ticking 'invert condition' on the 'complete match' variable, and its effect is not immediately obvious, but definitely not what I'm looking for.

Inicidentaly, someone else asked [a similar question](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5275370) on the IntelliJ forums, but got no love. Help me out, stackoverflow!

Answer (score 3):

To find classes that implement InterfaceA, but don't implement InterfaceB, I did the following:

1. Search > Search Structurally
2. Click **Copy existing template**
3. Select **implementors of an interface (within hierarcy)** and click **OK**
4. Click **Edit Variables**
5. Select **Interface** in the **Variables** list
6. Enter **InterfaceA** in **Text / regular expression** and click **OK**
7. Click **Find**
8. Search > Search Structurally
9. Click **Edit Variables**
10. Select **Interface** in the **Variables** list
11. Enter **InterfaceB** in **Text / regular expression**, **0** in **Minimum Count** and **0** in **Maximum Count** and click **OK**
12. Select **Previous Search Results** in the **Scope** dropdown
13. Click **Find**

Note I had problems when I tried to use the **Edit Query** button at step 8.  I didn't research/retry, but going back to the menu and selecting Search > Search Structurally definitely worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, the second part of the search seems to eliminate classes that don't directly implement the unwanted interface, but doesn't exclude those that implement it via a base class:  

    `interface Good {}`  
    `interface Bad {}`  
    `class Base implements Bad {}`  
    `class NotFiltered extends Base implements Good {}`

Comment: I'm sorry, by the way, for not responding to your comment sooner. I do appreciate your help! But my IDEA Ultimate eval license expired, and I only just bought one, so I couldn't test your prescription.