# In Intellij IDEA, find classes that implement an interface but do not extend another class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

Using structural search in Intellij IDEA, how should the search template be if i want to find all the classes that implement an interface but do not extend another class? The templates separately are:

```
class $Class$ implements $Interface$ {}
```

and

```
class $Class$ extends $Parent$ {}
```

setting minimum and maximum 1,1 and 0,0 respectively.

I tried something similar to this question without success:

[IntelliJ Structural Search to find classes that implement A but not B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254930/intellij-structural-search-to-find-classes-that-implement-a-but-not-b)

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the two templates:

```
class $Class$ extends $Parent$ implements $Interface$ {}
```

With the following variable settings

`$Parent$`:
Text/regexp `Excluded` and enable `Apply constrains in type hierarchy`, min/max `0,0`
`$Interface$`:
Text/regexp `Included` and enable `Apply constrains in type hierarchy`, min/max `1,1`

When I search with these settings on the following test code, classes `B` and `E` are found.

```
class Excluded {}
interface Included {}
class A extends Excluded implements Included {}
class B implements Included {}
class C extends Excluded {}
class D extends A {}
class E extends B {}
class F {}
```

You of course need to use your own class and interface name instead of Included and Excluded.

Comment: This doesn't work, even when assigning the min and max count to 1,1 and 0,0 respectively in your snippet.

Comment: I have added some more explanation. If this does not work for you, which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using? Maybe you're running into a bug.